# Change the label color in Google Static Maps

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I have custom coloured pins, which are all fairly dark in colour. The label defaults to black text, is there any way to make it white text so that it shows up on the dark pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of the Google static maps API (V2) it is not possible. Black is the only colour available.

Update: A workaround, albeit very hacky, is to upload the coloured text you want as images and use them as custom icons. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons